# Python crashes while using CopyFeatures in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.8 and ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 to automate some of the ArcGIS workflows with Python scripts. My code started crushing with no error message as follows:

[image: Python crush message]

The main issue was that there was no indication on the line, where it crushed or on the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out (with manual debugging with print statements) that the problem was with the following code part:

```
    name_cluster_head = '{0}_{1}'.format(i, output_name)
    out_cluster_head = os.path.join(output_fds, name_cluster_head)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(facilities_sublayer, out_cluster_head)
```

More specifically with arcpy.CopyFeatures_management. I have not really found any related issues online, so I have tried to avoid the function with:

```
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(facilities_sublayer, output_fds, name_cluster_head)
```

This resulted in the following error message:

[image: arcpy Feature to feature naming error message]

So it became clear that the problem was in the naming. The name starts with the number and it somehow creates the problem with arcpy. After changing to:

```
    name_cluster_head = 'Cluster_head_{0}_{1}'.format(i, output_name)
```

The issue was solved.

Comment: Using valid identifiers is of course required, but failure to do so shouldn't crash Python. If you can reproduce this with a modern ArcGIS build, then I would urge you to contact Tech Support.

Comment: @Vince, my point exactly. It should have worked as with arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion . I will think about further testing it, but at the moment I use only  10.3.1, so reported my problem. When I  have some time to install a newer version I will test it.